# Manhattan tourist

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In my algorithms and datastructures class I have been asked to implement the Manhattan tourist problem using dynamic programming.
I have come to a solution using a combination of dynamic programming and recursive calls, but I seem to get "Time limit exceeded" when putting it to the test on CodeJudge. I haven't been able to figure out why my code isn't fast enough. Any takers?
Best regards.

Description of the problem:
Your are helping the tourist guide company "Manhattan Tourists", that are arranging
guided tours of the city. They want to find a walk between two points on the map that is both interesting and short. The map is a square grid graph. The square grid graph has n rows with n nodes in each row. Let node vi,j denote the jth node on row i. For 1≤I<n and for 1≤j≤n node vi,j is connected to vi+1, j. And for 1≤i≤n and for 1 ≤ j < n node vi,j is connected to vi,j+1. The edges have non-negative edge weights that indicate how interesting that street is. See the graph below for an example of a 5 × 5 grid graph.
They want to find a short interesting walk from the upper left corner (s = v1,1) to the lower right corner (t = vn,n). More precisely, they want to find a path with the possible smallest number of edges, and among all paths with this number of edges they want the path with the maximum weight (the weight of a path is the sum of weights on the path).
All shortest paths have 2n − 2 edges and go from s to t by walking either down or right in each step. In the example below two possible shortest paths (of length 8) are indicated. The dashed path has weigth 38 and the dotted path has weight 30.

Let W [i, j] be the maximal weight you can get when walking from s to vi, j walking either down or right in each step. Let D[i, j] be the weight of the edge going down from vi, j and let R[i, j] be the weight of the edge going right from vi,j.

Description on CodeJudge:
Exercise
Before you can solve this exercise, you must first read, understand and (partly) solve the problem Manhattan Tourists described on the weekplan.
Your task here is to implement your solution. Read the input/output specification below and look at the sample test data in order to learn how to read the input and write the output.

Input format

- Line 1: The integer n (1<= n <= 1000).
- Line 2..n+1: the n rows of R, each consisting of n-1 integers separated by space.
- Line n+2..2n: the n-1 rows of D, each consisting of n integers separated by space.

Output format:
Line 1: The maximum interest score of a shortest walk.

Heres my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = console.nextInt();
    
    int[][] R = new int[n][n-1];
    int[][] D = new int[n-1][n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            R[i][j] = console.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            D[i][j] = console.nextInt();
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(opt(R, D, n, n-1, n-1));
}

public static int opt(int[][]R, int[][]D, int n, int i, int j) {
    int[][] result = new int[n][n];
    
    if(i==0 && j==0) {
        if(result[i][j] == 0) {
            result[i][j] = 0;
        }
        return result[i][j];
        
    } else if(i == 0) {
        if(result[i][j] == 0) {
            result[i][j] = opt(R,D,n,i,j-1) + R[i][j-1];
        }
        return result[i][j];
        
    }else if(j == 0) {
        if(result[i][j] == 0) {
            result[i][j] = opt(R,D,n,i-1,j) + D[i-1][j];
        }
        return result[i][j];
        
    }else if(result[i][j] == 0) {
        result[i][j] = max(opt(R, D, n, i, j-1) + R[i][j-1],opt(R, D, n, i-1, j) + D[i-1][j]);
    }
    
    return result[i][j];
}


public static int max(int i, int j) {
    if(i > j) {
        return i;
    }
    return j;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the Problem description or the source link?  It's not clear to me what's the "Tourist problem".

Comment: @DanielHao i have added the description :)

Comment: @moredejlig Doesn't `int[][] result = new int[n][n];` create a new instance of the `result` array at every level of recursion? If so, your code is implementing a brute force recursive solution, and isn't using dynamic programming at all. You can test this theory by adding a final `else` that prints the message "Using memoized result". I expect that you'll never see that message.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you, an oversight on my part!
I have now put the initialization of the array into the main method and passed it as a parameter. This works!

Comment: @moredejlig Bravo! That's good to hear. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Why a recursion?

The topmost row can be traversed horizontally only. So, for each vertex in the first row the total weight is a sum of weights of branches to the left. You can compute all of them in a single loop as a running total across the row.

For each next row the total weight of the first vertex is a weight of the vertex above it plus the weight of the branch between them. And the total weight of each next vertex in the row is the bigger one from two possible when coming from above or from left.

All that can be computed iteratively with two nested loops.

Comment: you're right, but I guess when making the algorithm I went with the recursive solution instead of the bottom-up solution. No specific reason.